# WebGrid doesn´t update when binding to a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I´m making a site using MVC 3 and razor engine. I have a WebGrid that has a ViewModel as it´s source that it´s not updating. Weird thing is that it only updates when I recompile the project, and I wanted to update it with an ajax call or at the very least with a page refresh.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yeah, why it´s happening that?

Comment: You need to provide some more details, we can not guess what is wrong.  Please show us the code that is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it but I don't know why it didn't work with the first solution I came up with. I had a static method in my ViewModel that retuned the list of Viewmodel objects that the webgrid used as it's model. It queried from two different databases and populated the Viewmodel objects.

I had to move that method to the controller and use the Viewmodel objects just as containers for the data to be passed to the webgrid and it worked.